# How can I create a polymophic relation factory so that I can use it on my phpunit tests?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have `articles` table and `comments` table. `comments` table includes `commentable_id commentable_type` and `body`. I tried the code below on my `testcase` which doesn't seem right. With this one I cannot create multiple `comments`.

```
/** @test */
    public function an_authenticated_user_can_comment_a_post(){

        $user = $this->signIn();

        $article = factory('App\Article')->create();

        $this->post("article/{$article->slug}/comment", [
            'comment' => $this->faker->sentence,
        ]);

        $this->assertCount(1, $article->comments);

    }
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Currenly I cloned other project here I have 5.5 but I work at 5.7

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Can't you add multiple comments 1 request, is it impossible to add multiple comments to 1 article?

Comment: @Loek yes this is working.. I just want a `factory` to add `comment`... since, its` polymorphic relation` how can I do that?

Comment: What are you testing here? If you are testing that an authenticated user can post a comment but hitting that endpoint, then I don't think you want to create a comment with a factory in your test. Your current test looks fine to me.